# Refresh Hibernate cache across the contexts

Tags: java, hibernate, caching

I have two context on single tomcat pointing to same database. I am using `ehcache` for 2nd level caching with Hibernate.
Now, when I do any create/update/delete operation on database, it reflect in `contect1` cache but to update in `contecxt2` cache, it took almost 15-20 min. I can't use refresh/clear function in `context2` as I don't know when to refresh.

How Can I refresh `context2's` Hibernate cache when there is any update happened through `context1`?

Also to do clustering for Hibernate cache, I need to give IP address and port number, but in my case, both are same for two contexts. So I think I can't use Hibernate cache clustering.